# How to use custom pool assignment for FairScheduler in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to take advantage of multiple pools in FairScheduler. But all my jobs are submitted by a single agent process and therefore all belong to same user.

I have set mapred.fairscheduler.poolnameproperty to scheduler.pool.name and then in each job I set "scheduler.pool.name" to a specific pool from pools.xml that I want to use for that job.
I can see in job configuration web page that both properties have values as expected and scheduler webpage shows all pools I am trying to use. However all jobs are still running in the pool %username% where username is name of the user that was used to submit all jobs.
I am running hadoop version 0.20.1 from Cloudera distribution.

Any ideas how to make my jobs run in a pool that is not dependent on the name of the user, who submitted the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like restart of jobtracker was not sufficient to effect new configuration. After restart of all tasktrackers and a jobtracker pool assignment works as expected.